# Spring + eclipselink transaction rollback not working

Tags: java, spring, eclipselink, transactional

In my service class, when exception is throwed, rollback is not working, what is wrong?

UserTest class

```
 @Test
public void checkCreatingAdminUser() throws AppException {

    String name = "Admin 1";
    String username = "admin1";
    String password = "Adminuser1";

    Assert.assertTrue(AppUtils.matchesPasswordMask(password));

    Boolean active = true;
    String email = "admin1@ad.ru";

    try {
        Assert.assertNull(userService.findByUsername(username));

        User user = userService.createAdminUser(name, username, password, active, email);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TEST FAILES HERE!
        Assert.assertNull(userService.findByUsername(username));
    }
}
```

UserService class

```
public interface UserService {


        User createAdminUser(String name, String username, String password, Boolean active, String email) throws AppException;

        User findByUsername(String username);
    }
```

Implementation service class

```
 @Override
public User createAdminUser(String name, String username, String password, Boolean active, String email) throws AppException {
    if (findByUsername(username) != null) {
        throw new AppException(AppError.USER_EXISTS_BY_USERNAME);
    }

    try {
        return createAdminUserTr(name, username, password, active, email);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error on create admin group", e);
        throw new AppException(AppError.DB_INTERNAL_ERROR);
    }
}

 @Transactional
public User createAdminUserTr(String name, String username, String password, Boolean active, String email) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(name);
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(hashPassword(password));
    user.setActive(active);
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setCreateDate(new Date());

    userRepository.save(user);

    throw new RuntimeException("check rollback test");

}
```

I think that problem is in my configurations, but I didn't find it

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mymemdb"/>
        <property name="user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="3"/>
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MAR-TEST-PU"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="my.app.models"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories
            base-package="my.app.repositories"
            entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
            transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"
    />
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean name="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.app"/>

</beans>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: 1. Invoking `createAdminUserTr` from another method does not pay attention to `Transactional` annotation. `createAdminUser` method  should be marked as `Transactional`, not `createAdminUserTr`. 2. `AppException` seems to be checked one. They do not rollback the transaction by default.

Comment: Hi Andriy! You are right for 1), 2).  Tell me please, how to catch exception in transactional method in service layer and wrap to my own AppException?

Comment: It depends on how you want to handle it. Default approach is: unchecked exceptions rollback the transaction but checked exceptions by definition require catch block where you may or may not rollback. Nevertheless sometimes is convenient to customize these behavior. There is an attribute `rollbackFor` of `Transactional` annotation for example.